# Find size of numpy array within a Panda dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the size of each numpy array within a panda. How do I do this?
I have:

```
          x          y                      z
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [8, 9, 7]              [8, 9, 7]
1  [2, 3, 4, 8]  [9, 8, 1]  [9, 8, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2     [5, 6, 7]  [3, 4, 1]              [3, 4, 1]


cars= pd.DataFrame({'x': [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,8],[5,6,7]],
                    'y': [[8,9,7],[9,8,1],[3,4,1]],
                    'z': [[8,9,7],[9,8,1,6,7,8,9],[3,4,1]]})
```

I want:

```
   x  y  z
0  4  3  3
1  4  3  7
2  3  3  3
```

I know how to get the shape and size of the entire DataFrame, but not how to combine them with size of each block.

```
print(cars)
print(cars.size)
print(cars.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for precessing all columns:

```
df = cars.apply(lambda x: x.str.len())
print (df)
   x  y  z
0  4  3  3
1  4  3  7
2  3  3  3
```

If no missing values use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for element-wise apply function `len` :

```
df = cars.applymap(len)
```